# Passing an elementId to getElementById by reference

Tags: javascript, html

I have a number of slider controls on an page. 
They all behave in exactly the same way, and I'm wanting to drive the slider behavior with one JavaScript function.

I'm struggling to pass the name of the slider that is triggering this function, and which is the one that needs to be affected by the function.

**Here's my HTML Code**

```
<td>
    <input name="ScoreNoSurprises" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="5" step="1" 
    onchange="showValue(this.value,"ScoreNoSurprises")" />
    <span id="ScoreNoSurprises">5</span>
</td>
```

**And my javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function showValue(newValue, elementID)
   {
    window.alert("Element is: " + elementID);
    document.getElementById(elementID).innerHTML=newValue;
   }
</script>
```

Is this possible? What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: onchange="showValue(this.value,"ScoreNoSurprises")" - " inside of "! Change the inner "s to 's!

Comment: Dang! That's embarrassing. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You are nesting quotes. 
The parser would read `onchange="showValue(this.value,"ScoreNoSurprises")"` as `onchange="showValue(this.value,"` which would throw an error.

Then it would read the HTML: `ScoreNoSurprises")"` which does nothing.

Furthermore you could use events. (Note that, in this example, you have to add a classname to the input element)

```js
//You can use this instead of onchange=""
Array.prototype.forEach.call(//Changing 'this' for Array.forEach
  document.getElementsByClassName("ScoreNoSurprises"),function(element){
//This uses the Array.forEach method in the Element Pseudo array returned by document.getElementsByClassName.
//In other words this will select every element classed as "ScoreNoSurprises" 
//which IS better if you have many of these elements, and it keeps JavaScript off the HTML, so there will be less cluttering.
  element.addEventListener("change",function(){
//This adds an 'change event listener to Event'
   showValue(element.value,"ScoreNoSurprises");
  },false);
});
   function showValue(newValue, elementID)
   {
    window.alert("Element is: " + elementID);
    document.getElementById(elementID).innerHTML=newValue;
   }
```

```html
<input name="ScoreNoSurprises" class="ScoreNoSurprises" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="5" step="1" /><!--No onchange needed!-->
    <span id="ScoreNoSurprises">5</span>
```

This *does* look more complicated at first hand, but as code grows more complex it might be helpful in removing repetition, and controlling all the code in one point.
This might be better in some situations.